# predicting a incoming sentence in a if statement? c#

Tags: c#, voice

my problem is that i am trying to predict a key within a dictionary after this string "what is the weather like in". So you probably know already what this is after that sentence. I am making an weather application with voice recognition. And i need "what is the weather like in" to be static and after that sentence a city comes. For example "what is the weather like in gothenburg". where gothenburg is a recognized city in my dictionary i have.

I tried with

```
static Dictionary<string, int> cityList = new Dictionary<string, int>();
if (e.PartialResult.ToString() == string.Format("what is the weather like in {0}", cityList.ContainsKey(e.PartialResult.ToString().Trim("what is the weather like in ".ToArray()))))
{
            string city = e.PartialResult.ToString();
            city = city.Trim("what is the weather like in ".ToArray());
            int cityId = cityList[city]; //here is just city the recognized "city" from the voice recognition
}
```

however that didn't work, if statement is not true when i say for example "what is the weather like in gothenburg". the triming on the end of the if statement is just to get the "said" city standalone. If i wouldnt trim it that would be "what is the weather like in city" and not just "city".

this is the recognized i got when i tried "what is the weather like in south park". "south park" is in my dictionary so i have no clue why the code in the if statement is not being run when this is recognized. seems right to me?

basicly the if statement is suppose to be able to predict multiple city's. "what is the weather like in gothenburg" , "what is the weather like in denmark". You name it, what i do with the city that is recognized is that i trim down that whole string so that the city is just standalone. where i seach my dictionary for an int value by the string. so that i can send out that id to the weather api server and get back a proper response just for that city that was recognized

i am using bing speech api if that makes any difference in solving this issue.

Comment: Your `Trim` call makes no sense, but could you please debug your code and [edit] post to clarify if problem is in speech recognition part or your string manipulation? See [MCVE] for guidance.

Comment: i am trying to predict "what is the weather like in "city" " in my if statement. where "city" is a key in my dictionary. "city" is dynamic because i have alot of city's in my dictionary and "what is the weather like in" is static because that sentence should never change

Comment: basicly the if statement is suppose to be able to predict multiple city's. "what is the weather like in gothenburg" , "what is the weather like in denmark". You name it, what i do with the city that is recognized is that i trim down that whole string so that the city is just standalone. where i seach my dictionary for an int value by the string. so that i can send out that id to the weather api server and get back a proper response just for that city that was recognized

Comment: `if (e.PartialResult.StartsWith(whatIsWeatherLike) && cityList.TryGetValue(e.PartialResult.Substring(whatIsWeatherLike.Length).Trim(), out city)) { return GetWeather(city); }`

Comment: You can't pass a string to the `.Trim()` method, but you can call `.Substring()` and pass in `"what is the weather like in".Length` as the starting index for the partial string (after first ensuring that the original string `.StartsWith("what is the weather like in")`). And the handy thing about `TryGetValue` is that it both tells you if the key exists and returns the key to you if it does (in the `out` parameter)

Comment: oh okay : ), but will this only return the "city" ? im getting error "cannot convert 'out string' to 'out int'.

Comment: seems like it will return an int instead of a string? i need it to out a string because with that string i am searching the dictionary with that string to get the "id" in the dictionary assosiated with that city.                int cityId = cityList[city];

Comment: It returns the `value` associated with the `key` that it found. In your case, it is the `int` associated with the `string city` key.

Comment: No you don't...this is both finding the key AND returning the int value. `city` in my example is the `int` value associated with the city.

Comment: oh okay nice! so it is already returning the int assosiated with that string from the dictionary? that is cool ^^

Comment: Yeah. Check out the [`Dictionary.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation for more info.

Comment: Yep this works. Thanks to @RufusL !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a more readable example of what I was talking about in the comments.

1. What we can do is first check if the user input [`.StartsWith`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the weather query string (in a case-insensitive manner below).
2. If that's true, then we can get the city portion of the string by calling [`.Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) on the user input and passing in the length of our weather query. This will return the rest of the string.
3. Finally we can pass this to the [`.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) method on the `cityList` dictionary, which will search the keys for that string and, if found, set the [`out` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) to the `cityId` value associated with that city in the dictionary.

Also notice that we should initialize our dictionary with a case-insensitive comparer, just to be sure we don't miss a key because of some capitalization.

For example:

```
static Dictionary<string, int> cityList = 
    new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

static void SomeMethod(SomeType e)
{
    var weatherQuery = "what is the weather like in";
    int cityId;

    string userInput = e.PartialResult.ToString().Trim();

    if (userInput.StartsWith(weatherQuery, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        cityList.TryGetValue(userInput.Substring(weatherQuery.Length).Trim(), out cityId))
    {
        // We have a weather query and have located the cityId
        CallSomeWeatherAPI(cityId);
    }
}
```